# PostgreSQL 9.5: Return dynamic columns list

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function to return the records from different tables based on given condition to 
the function.

**Function**: `udf_dynamic_returns`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_dynamic_returns
(
    condition_name varchar(10)
)
RETURNS ????

AS

$BODY$

BEGIN

    IF condition_name = 'A' 
    THEN

        SELECT col1,col2,col3
        FROM Test

    ELSE IF condition_name = 'B' 
    THEN

        SELECT col21col22,col23,col24,col25
        FROM Kon

    ELSE IF condition_name = 'C' 
    THEN

        SELECT col31,col32
        FROM Mat

    ELSE IF condition_name = 'D' 
    THEN

        SELECT col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
        FROM Test
    ......
    ......

    END IF

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**Note**: I have many conditions to check within the function.

By searching i came to know about [Polymorphic Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/extend-type-system.html). But i don't think it's really a good idea to create so many `Composite types`.

Comment: Mention the reason in the comment for down vote.

Comment: Look at the [`declare cursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html), [`prepare`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html), [`create temp view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html), [`plpgsql refcursors`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

Comment: There is workaround with cursors - @Abelisto hint - but more or less it is signal of wrong design - any PL function should to returns scalar, array or table of known stable type. PLpgSQL (PostgreSQL) is pretty static - the patterns from dynamic languages or from MSSQL are not practical, available here. Think about PLpgSQL, about Postgres they are like compilers. Maybe your design needs some rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `RETURNS RECORD` or `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`.

But then the caller must specify the column-list when invoking the function. PostgreSQL's planner does not currently know how to execute the function to determine its result-columns-list, then parse and plan the rest of the query once it knows the result-column-list for the function.

See the PostgreSQL documentation chapter on returning records.